# Button color-Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, colors

I want to change color of button in red. That work in WP7 Portrait page.

```
Brush op = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
button1.Background = op;
```

But now that don't work in Panorama page in off course WP7, C#.
Help pls.
Windows Phone 7

Comment: <Button 
                
                Grid.Column="4"
                Grid.Row="5"
                
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0"
                Background="Pink"
                Name="button1" 
                 Click="button1_Click" 
                BorderThickness="3" 
                
                
                />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working for me. I hope you have not done any style binding to the button. The style binding overrides the changes done at the code behind. That is what is happening in my panorama. A simple button is working but a button with style binding is not working. Could you post your xaml code?

Comment: <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Background="Pink" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" BorderThickness="3" />

Comment: Still working for me. I hope you not doing anything stupid. Xaml has you button and your c# code is in the code behind. Try to revisit your code and look for glitches

Comment: Did you try it in Panorama project?

Comment: Thanks, I create new one, by the way how can I open new xaml in C# WPF by click on button, thanks?

Comment: in click event handler function call `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/path/page.xaml",UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(System.Uri)' (CS0120) - C:\Users\Dario\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Panorama-Kocka\Panorama-Kocka\Window1.xaml.cs:48,10

Comment: If its giving you error try `this.NavigationService...`. If still shit happens could you post your full function defination once?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         
         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Window2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
         
        }

Comment: I am not getting that error. I wonder what you are doing. are you using static classes somewhere? Try `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Window2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: 'Panorama_Kocka.Window1' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService' and no extension method 'NavigationService' accepting a first argument of type 'Panorama_Kocka.Window1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) - C:\Users\Dario\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Panorama-Kocka\Panorama-Kocka\Window1.xaml.cs:48,15

Comment: why `public partial class Window1 : Window`? it should be `public partial class PageName : PhoneApplicationPage`.

Comment: That is WPF , windows application.

Comment: then why tag it as windows phone?? All the time i had been testing it for windows phone. Even in the question u say WP7. I am really confused now :P